# I need to create a pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

I have a data in Azure datalake I need to create a pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake  (in my case destination is an API) without using dataflow transformation.

[image]

sample input text file:

```
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers
21                      83              SD           225             SD2        "5","10","20","30","40","41","42","43","44","93"
```

Required json output:

```
{
    "BannerNumber": "21",
    "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
    "StoreGroupName": "SD",
    "StoreGroupMembers": [
        {
            "MemberId": "225",
            "MemberLabel": "SD2",
            "StoreNumbers": [
                {
                    "StoreId": "5"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "10"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "20"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "30"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "40"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "41"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "42"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "43"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "44"
                },
                {
                    "StoreId": "93"
                }
            ],
            "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 
        }
        ]
}
```

With dataflow i have done but as per the requirement they need it without using the dataflow

Comment: Are you talking about Azure Data factory pipelines?

Comment: Is your input data is a csv file with commas? provide correct format of the input data?

Comment: Yes it's a csv file 
BannerNumber StoreGroupNumber StoreGroupName MemberNumber MemberName StoreNumbers

"21"," 83", "SD", "225", "SD2", "\"5",\"10\",\"20\",\"30\",\"40\",\"41\",\"42\",\"43\",\"44\",\"93\""

Comment: yes azure data factory pipeline

Comment: Yes it's a csv file it looks like
 BannerNumber StoreGroupNumber StoreGroupName MemberNumber MemberName StoreNumbers 
"21"," 83", "SD", "225", "SD2", "\"5",\"10\",\"20\",\"30\",\"40\",\"41\",\"42\",\"43\",\"44\",\"93\""
last data is for store numbers 
please help me on this..

Comment: I think I need to see your csv data picture like columns and rows. Can you provide your sample csv picture? Please edit your question to add it. Is your csv file looks like this https://i.imgur.com/CE6HYbt.png?

Comment: i have added 
able to see ?

Comment: Could you please do it for this sample data.....i.imgur.com/CE6HYbt.png? 
which you have created

Comment: I have one approach but it will only if your CSV size is less than 4 MB or 5000 rows?

Comment: yeah its less than 4mb and 5000 rows

Comment: Could you please suggest the approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these kind of requirement involves row and column operations Dataflow is the better option than below method.

> Could you please do it for this sample data.....i.imgur.com/CE6HYbt.png? which you have created

**NOTE:** This will only work for this kind of data and in this method it involves some manual steps to build the required JSON.

I took a tab seperated csv file with multiple rows as sample data:

```
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers
21  83  SD  225 SD2 "5","10","20","30","40","41","42","43","44","93"
22  84  SA  226 SD3 "6","11","21","31","41","42","43","44","45","94"
23  85  SB  227 SD4 "7","12","22","32","42","43","44","45","46","95"
```

As it is Tab seperated, Give column delimiter as `\t` in the dataset settings.

[image]

In the pipeline, take a **lookup activity** for the above dataset and **uncheck the First row only** in it.
This lookup will give the JSON array and we can use this JSON array to build the required JSON array.

Create two variables `json_arr`,`curr_date` of array and string type respectively. The extra variable is only for showing the result here and its not necessary.

[image]

Then, take a set variable activity and give the below expression for the `curr_date` expression. This is for the date in required JSON.

```
@utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff')
```

Give the lookup activity output array `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to the ForEach activity and make sure you check the `Seuential` in the ForEach.

Inside ForEach activity, take an append variable activity for the `json_arr` variable with the below expression.

```
@json(concat('{"BannerNumber":"',item().BannerNumber,'","StoreGroupNumber":"',item().StoreGroupNumber,'","StoreGroupName":"',item().StoreGroupName,'","StoreGroupMembers":[{"MemberId":"',item().MemberNumber,'","MemberLabel":"',item().MemberName,'","StoreNumbers":[{"StoreId":',replace(item().StoreNumbers,',','},{"StoreId":'),'}],"MemberAddedOn": "',variables('curr_date'),'"}]}'))
```

[image]

This will append every row as object to the `json_arr` variable in each iteration.

**After ForEach, the result JSON array will be like this:**

[image]

```
[
        {
            "BannerNumber": "21",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
            "StoreGroupName": "SD",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "225",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD2",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "40"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "41"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "42"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "43"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "44"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "93"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-11-15 07:06:10.6985713"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BannerNumber": "22",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "84",
            "StoreGroupName": "SA",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "226",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD3",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "11"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "21"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "31"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "41"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "42"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "43"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "44"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "45"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "94"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-11-15 07:06:10.6985713"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BannerNumber": "23",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "85",
            "StoreGroupName": "SB",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "227",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD4",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "7"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "12"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "22"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "32"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "42"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "43"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "44"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "45"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "46"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "95"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-11-15 07:06:10.6985713"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

> in my case destination is an API

You can send this JSON to your destination API using web activity POST method.

**This is my pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Date",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "json_arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{\"BannerNumber\":\"',item().BannerNumber,'\",\"StoreGroupNumber\":\"',item().StoreGroupNumber,'\",\"StoreGroupName\":\"',item().StoreGroupName,'\",\"StoreGroupMembers\":[{\"MemberId\":\"',item().MemberNumber,'\",\"MemberLabel\":\"',item().MemberName,'\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":',replace(item().StoreNumbers,',','},{\"StoreId\":'),'}],\"MemberAddedOn\": \"',variables('curr_date'),'\"}]}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "res_show_arr",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('json_arr')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Date",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "curr_date",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "json_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "res_show_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "curr_date": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much 
Rakesh one last quetion 
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers
"21",  "83",  "SD",  "225", "SD2", "5","10","20","30","40","41","42","43","44","93"
what if the data looks like this....any suggestion

Comment: or 
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName 
"21",  "83",  "SD",  "225", "SD2",
store numbers 
"\"5",\"10\",\"20\",\"30\",\"40\",\"41\",\"42\",\"43\",\"44\",\"93\""
this kind of data any suggestion

Comment: I don't think this kind of data works. because this data has 2 delimiters `\t` in headers and `,` in the rows. To work on the csv data with lookup your column delimiter should be same for all data and also your `StoreNumbers` has `,` between the numbers so thats why your column delimiter should be different from `,`.

Comment: Ok is there any way to convert that csv file data.
To required format

Comment: I think it's better to raise a new question on this ask with all the required details. The community also might assist, and I will also try if it's to my knowledge.

Comment: Okay 
Rakesh i have taken the input file which you have given as an input but 
in foreach the pipeline is failing....input its taking count 3 but output empty

every append variable is failing

could you please tell me where i have made mistake

Comment: what expression you gave in the Foreach? give `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` and use the next expression in the append variable activity?

Comment: I have added my pipeline JSON. Please check that while building your pipeline.

Comment: i have used your json but still in append we are getting this error

Comment: 'json(concat('{"BannerNumber":"',item().BannerNumber,'","StoreGroupNumber":"',item().StoreGroupNumber,'","StoreGroupName":"',item().StoreGroupName,'","StoreGroupMembers":[{"MemberId":"',item().MemberNumber,'","MemberLabel":"',item().MemberName,'","StoreNumbers":[{"StoreId":',replace(item().StoreNumbers,',','},{"StoreId":'),'}],"MemberAddedOn": "',variables('curr_date'),'"}]}'))' cannot be evaluated because property 'BannerNumber' doesn't exist, available properties are 'BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers'.

Comment: i have used your sample data in the dataset

Comment: Can you please show your append variable activity image? did you uncheck the FirstRow in the lookup activity?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYUi9.png


please check the image

Comment: did you uncheck the FirstRow in the lookup activity? 

Yes i unchecked

Comment: input data 
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJIYJ.png

Comment: Everything is fine and this should work. First publish your pipeline and dataset and try to reopen the ADF and execute the pipeline again.

Comment: ' cannot be evaluated because property 'BannerNumber' doesn't exist, available properties are 'BannerNumber StoreGroupNumber StoreGroupName MemberNumber MemberName StoreNumbers'.

this is taking all the column names as one

Comment: Did you gave the tab as column delimiter in the source dataset?

Comment: yes
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4wdt.png

Comment: Can you show your lookup output array as well?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kNq.png
this is the lookup output

Comment: could you please share the sample file which you have used in the dataset..

Comment: Your data is space separated so that's why it is taking all the columns as single column. The data should be Tab separated. Give tab instead of space in your data and it will work as expected.

Comment: i have copied from
your sample data which you have given above

Comment: My data is Tab seperated. for some reason even though I have given Tab seperated, it took space seperated in the answer. The data should be Tab seperated as I have mentioned in the answer. Just replace the space with a tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rakesh 
it worked for the data which i have in the datalake also

Comment: I have Marked it Thank you

Comment: For suppose if there is BannerNumber,StoreGroupNumber,StoreGroupName is same for few records the records needs to be append to the existing record.
in the cosmos 
is there any possibility to do that

Comment: is there any possibility to agrregate with a column name in the same pipeline
with out using dataflow

Comment: I think without dataflow, it might get very difficult to deal this kind of operations. Dataflow is designed for this kind of operations.

Comment: yes Rakesh we have done it with dataflow but to call the dataflow its taking 2 min there is a performance issue 
so we are looking for the other approach to do it

Comment: Then SQL script might be a good option. First get the above result JSON array then use the JSON array variable in SQL script activity. Explore aggregate operations in the SQL.

Comment: Ok Rakesh thank you we will explore

Comment: Not able to do...I have posted another question.Please look

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566422/i-need-to-create-a-pipeline-to-aggregate-the-data-and-change-it-to-json-format-g?noredirect=1#comment136749030_77566422