# Create a pipeline without data flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]How to aggregate or group by column names in azure data factory without using data flows?

I tried with data flows but.is there any other way to do one?

I want to get only aggregated data to loaded to azure SQL from  on-Prem SQL server. For example i have 99 records,  but I want to load only 5 distinct records based on aggregation?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you source is? And show some sample input and output you are expecting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480928/i-need-to-create-a-pipeline-to-set-it-in-the-required-format-given-below-and-loa

Comment: Can you refer this question after converting json, we have to aggregate by column names

Comment: Since you are copying the data to azure SQL database, you can use `script activity` in ADF and write a sql query for aggregating.

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: you can run the stored procedure in your SQL Server that performs the necessary aggregation, and use the stored procedure [activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) in ADF to execute this procedure

Solution2: you can run a direct SQL query that performs the aggregation or grouping during the run activity