# I need to create a pipeline to aggregate the data and change it to Json format given below without using dataflow activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data in Azure datalake I need to create a ADF pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake (in my case destination is an API) without using dataflow transformation.
Note: Aggregate on BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName this column.

Input data:

```
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers
21                      83              SD           225             SD2        "5","10","20","30","40","41"
21                      83              SD           225             SD3        "6","10","20"
22                      84              SD           226             SD3        "43","44"
```

Required output 1st row:

```
{

    "BannerNumber": "21",

    "StoreGroupNumber": "83",

    "StoreGroupName": "SD",

    "StoreGroupMembers": [

        {

            "MemberId": "225",

            "MemberLabel": "SD2",

            "StoreNumbers": [

                {

                    "StoreId": "5"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "10"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "20"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "30"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "40"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "41"

                }

            ],

            "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

        },

         {

            "MemberId": "225",

            "MemberLabel": "SD3",

            "StoreNumbers": [

                {

                    "StoreId": "6"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "10"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "20"

                }

                ],

             "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

}            

        ]

}
```

Required output 2nd row:

```
{

    "BannerNumber": "22",

    "StoreGroupNumber": "84",

    "StoreGroupName": "SD",

    "StoreGroupMembers": [

        {

            "MemberId": "226",

            "MemberLabel": "SD3",

            "StoreNumbers": [

                {

                    "StoreId": "43"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "44"

                }

            ],

            "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

        }

        ]

        }
```

Comment: Please help us in this scenario

Comment: Data transformation is not possible with ADF pipelines, you should use mapping data flow to get required form.

Comment: with dataflow we have created
 and for the format i have posted a question in stack overflow we are getting format but aggregating how to do that we dont have an idea.....please refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480928/i-need-to-create-a-pipeline-to-set-it-in-the-required-format-given-below-and-loa?noredirect=1#comment136603380_77480928

Comment: Anyone please suggests the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lookup activity to get JSON data from the data lake.
Lookup output:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "BannerNumber": "21",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
            "StoreGroupName": "SD",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "225",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD2",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "40"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "41"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000"
                },
                {
                    "MemberId": "225",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD3",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "20"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BannerNumber": "21",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
            "StoreGroupName": "SD",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "225",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD2",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "40"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "41"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000"
                },
                {
                    "MemberId": "225",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD3",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "20"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BannerNumber": "22",
            "StoreGroupNumber": "84",
            "StoreGroupName": "SD",
            "StoreGroupMembers": [
                {
                    "MemberId": "226",
                    "MemberLabel": "SD3",
                    "StoreNumbers": [
                        {
                            "StoreId": "43"
                        },
                        {
                            "StoreId": "44"
                        }
                    ],
                    "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

Create a dummy SQL database, and create an SQL database linked service. Use the script below to aggregate the JSON:

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}';

SELECT 
    BannerNumber,
    MAX(StoreGroupNumber) AS StoreGroupNumber,
    MAX(StoreGroupName) AS StoreGroupName,
    '[' + STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StoreGroupMembers)
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        t.StoreGroupMembers
                    FROM OPENJSON(@json1)
                    WITH (
                        BannerNumber varchar(10),
                        StoreGroupNumber varchar(10),
                        StoreGroupName varchar(50),
                        StoreGroupMembers nvarchar(max) AS JSON
                    ) t
                    WHERE t.BannerNumber = OuterQuery.BannerNumber
                ) AS InnerQuery
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
        ) + ']' AS StoreGroupMembers
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.BannerNumber,
        t.StoreGroupNumber,
        t.StoreGroupName
    FROM OPENJSON(@json1)
    WITH (
        BannerNumber varchar(10),
        StoreGroupNumber varchar(10),
        StoreGroupName varchar(50),
        StoreGroupMembers nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    ) t
) AS OuterQuery
GROUP BY BannerNumber;
```

You will get the JSON in the required format as shown below:

[image]

```
{
    "BannerNumber": "21",
    "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
    "StoreGroupName": "SD",
    "StoreGroupMembers": "[[{\"MemberId\":\"225\",\"MemberLabel\":\"SD2\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":\"5\"},{\"StoreId\":\"10\"},{\"StoreId\":\"20\"},{\"StoreId\":\"30\"},{\"StoreId\":\"40\"},{\"StoreId\":\"41\"}],\"MemberAddedOn\":\"2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000\"},{\"MemberId\":\"225\",\"MemberLabel\":\"SD3\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":\"6\"},{\"StoreId\":\"10\"},{\"StoreId\":\"20\"}],\"MemberAddedOn\":\"2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000\"}],[{\"MemberId\":\"225\",\"MemberLabel\":\"SD2\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":\"5\"},{\"StoreId\":\"10\"},{\"StoreId\":\"20\"},{\"StoreId\":\"30\"},{\"StoreId\":\"40\"},{\"StoreId\":\"41\"}],\"MemberAddedOn\":\"2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000\"},{\"MemberId\":\"225\",\"MemberLabel\":\"SD3\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":\"6\"},{\"StoreId\":\"10\"},{\"StoreId\":\"20\"}],\"MemberAddedOn\":\"2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000\"}]]"
},
{
    "BannerNumber": "22",
    "StoreGroupNumber": "84",
    "StoreGroupName": "SD",
    "StoreGroupMembers": "[[{\"MemberId\":\"226\",\"MemberLabel\":\"SD3\",\"StoreNumbers\":[{\"StoreId\":\"43\"},{\"StoreId\":\"44\"}],\"MemberAddedOn\":\"2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000\"}]]"
}
```

Pipeline Json for your reference:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": false,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Script1",
                "type": "Script",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "scripts": [
                        {
                            "type": "Query",
                            "text": "DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}';\n\nSELECT \n    BannerNumber,\n    MAX(StoreGroupNumber) AS StoreGroupNumber,\n    MAX(StoreGroupName) AS StoreGroupName,\n    '[' + STUFF(\n            (\n                SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StoreGroupMembers)\n                FROM (\n                    SELECT \n                        t.StoreGroupMembers\n                    FROM OPENJSON(@json1)\n                    WITH (\n                        BannerNumber varchar(10),\n                        StoreGroupNumber varchar(10),\n                        StoreGroupName varchar(50),\n                        StoreGroupMembers nvarchar(max) AS JSON\n                    ) t\n                    WHERE t.BannerNumber = OuterQuery.BannerNumber\n                ) AS InnerQuery\n                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE\n            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''\n        ) + ']' AS StoreGroupMembers\nFROM (\n    SELECT \n        t.BannerNumber,\n        t.StoreGroupNumber,\n        t.StoreGroupName\n    FROM OPENJSON(@json1)\n    WITH (\n        BannerNumber varchar(10),\n        StoreGroupNumber varchar(10),\n        StoreGroupName varchar(50),\n        StoreGroupMembers nvarchar(max) AS JSON\n    ) t\n) AS OuterQuery\nGROUP BY BannerNumber;\n\n"
                        }
                    ],
                    "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout": "02:00:00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "bn": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Thank you could you please share whole json file for the pipeline.....

Comment: @Laxman I have updated the answer with pipeline Json.