# we need to create a pipeline to aggregate the data and change it to Json format given below without using dataflow activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a data in Azure datalake I need to create a ADF pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake (in my case destination is an API) without using dataflow transformation. Note: Aggregate on BannerNumber StoreGroupNumber StoreGroupName this column.
INPUT DATA:

```
BannerNumber    StoreGroupNumber    StoreGroupName  MemberNumber    MemberName  StoreNumbers
21                      83              SD           225             SD2       "5","10","20","30","40","41"
21                      83              SD           225             SD3        "6","10","20"
22                      84              SD           226             SD3        "43","44"
```

Required output 1st row:

```
{

    "BannerNumber": "21",

    "StoreGroupNumber": "83",

    "StoreGroupName": "SD",

    "StoreGroupMembers": [

        {

            "MemberId": "225",

            "MemberLabel": "SD2",

            "StoreNumbers": [

                {

                    "StoreId": "5"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "10"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "20"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "30"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "40"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "41"

                }

            ],

            "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

        },

         {

            "MemberId": "225",

            "MemberLabel": "SD3",

            "StoreNumbers": [

                {

                    "StoreId": "6"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "10"

                },

                {

                    "StoreId": "20"

                }

                ],

             "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

}            

        ]

}
```

Required output 2nd row:

```
{

"BannerNumber": "22",

"StoreGroupNumber": "84",

"StoreGroupName": "SD",

"StoreGroupMembers": [

    {

        "MemberId": "226",

        "MemberLabel": "SD3",

        "StoreNumbers": [

            {

                "StoreId": "43"

            },

            {

                "StoreId": "44"

            }

        ],

        "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000",---Need to be todays date 

    }

    ]

    }
```

[I need to create a pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480928/i-need-to-create-a-pipeline-to-set-it-in-the-required-format-given-below-and-loa?noredirect=1#comment136603380_77480928),

With above approach we are getting format but not in aggregate data

Comment: Are you repeating the input data twice in the question?

Comment: Now i made changes, thanks for highlighting

Comment: This is not possible just with ADF pipeline

Comment: If you dont want to use dataflow, can you try using synapse sql notebook or pyspark notebook ?